# SQL - Group By Select Query is close but I need to make it slightly more unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

**Updated for more clarity**

SQL Sever 2000. I'm trying to make this query slightly more unique.

The Query:

```
USE MyDatabase
GO

SELECT MAX(x.provider_entry_id) as provider_entry_id,  -- this ID is the PK
     x.provider_entry_type_id, -- the entry for the specific provider type (the ID)
     x.provider_entry, -- the actual provider entry (the ID)
     x.provider_entry_visit_dt -- the date the entry was created
FROM tbl_claimant_provider_entry x
JOIN (SELECT p.provider_entry_type_id,
             p.provider_entry,
             MAX(provider_entry_visit_dt) AS max_date
        FROM tbl_claimant_provider_entry p
        WHERE provider_entry_clmnt = 4963 -- change this for you user 
        GROUP BY p.provider_entry_type_id, p.provider_entry) y ON y.provider_entry_type_id = x.provider_entry_type_id
                          AND y.max_date = x.provider_entry_visit_dt
GROUP BY x.provider_entry_type_id, x.provider_entry, x.provider_entry_visit_dt
```

returns:

```
provider_entry_id   provider_entry_type_id  provider_entry  provider_entry_visit_dt
1052                109                     1088            2013-01-22 00:00:00.000
1051                109                     1665            2013-01-23 00:00:00.000
1049                130                     264             2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
1050                130                     1126            2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
1045                132                     NULL            2013-01-22 00:00:00.000
1047                132                     260             2013-01-22 00:00:00.000
1044                132                     1115            2013-01-10 00:00:00.000
1048                132                     1130            2013-01-22 00:00:00.000
1043                142                     1356            2013-01-10 00:00:00.000
```

I'm looking to narrow this list to show me only one instance of each unique `provider_entry_type_id` based on the most recent `provider_entry_visit_dt`

So the results would be (keep in mind that there will not need to be a need for tie breakers for the provider_entry_visit_dt, that's just an error on my part):

```
provider_entry_id   provider_entry_type_id  provider_entry  provider_entry_visit_dt
1051                109                     1665            2013-01-23 00:00:00.000
1050                130                     1126            2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
1048                132                     1130            2013-01-22 00:00:00.000
1043                142                     1356            2013-01-10 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Use `distinct`?  We need more info on which one of the two to choose.

Comment: So which provider_entry and created_date do you want?

Comment: @JonH Looking to get the first (via entry ID) of the provider_entry_type_id

Comment: @AaronBertrand the most recent (hence MAX) created_date per unique provider entry type. So I would only have provider_entry_id's 1047 and 1048 in this example.

Comment: But 1047 and 1048 both belong to 132. Which row do you want for 142? You'll also want a row for 1043, won't you? Can you provide sample data (e.g. show the original date for the two rows 1047 and 1048 instead of showing the max for both rows). It's hard to tell if you care whether the max id and the max created date come from the same original row or not.

Comment: @AaronBertrand that was a typo... I ONLY want 1047 for provider_entry_type_id 132 and 1043 which is should be unique to 142.

Comment: And do you want 1047 because it is associated with the latest create date in the table, because it is the lowest entry_id, or for some other reason?

Comment: actually now that I think about it 1048 would be created latest... not 1047. My desired results are the most recent entry for each provider_entry_type.

Comment: I updated the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that worked, thank you to all that tried to help:

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    dbo.tbl_claimant_provider_entry AS b 
INNER JOIN
            (SELECT provider_entry_type_id, MAX(provider_entry_visit_dt) AS maxdate
                            FROM    dbo.tbl_claimant_provider_entry
                            GROUP BY provider_entry_type_id) AS m ON b.provider_entry_type_id = m.provider_entry_type_id AND b.provider_entry_visit_dt = m.maxdate
WHERE   (b.provider_entry_clmnt = 4963)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the outer `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT  x.*
FROM    tbl_claimant_provider_entry x
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  p.provider_entry_type_id,
                    MAX(created_date) AS max_date
            FROM    tbl_claimant_provider_entry p
            WHERE   provider_entry_clmnt = 4963 -- change this for you user ID
            GROUP   BY p.provider_entry_type_id
        ) y ON  y.provider_entry_type_id = x.provider_entry_type_id AND 
                y.max_date = x.created_date
```

Comment: This gives me the same record set (with all the columns in the table, of course).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove created_date from the group by statement. You can put a function on it to leave it in the query (i.e. a function like you have for provider_entry_id). For example:

```
SELECT MAX(x.provider_entry_id) as provider_entry_id,  -- this ID is the PK
         MAX(x.created_date),
         x.provider_entry_type_id, -- the entry for the specific provider type (the ID)
         MIN(x.provider_entry) -- the actual provider entry (the ID)
    FROM tbl_claimant_provider_entry x
    JOIN (SELECT p.provider_entry_type_id,
                 p.provider_entry,
                 MAX(created_date) AS max_date
            FROM tbl_claimant_provider_entry p
            WHERE provider_entry_clmnt = 4963 -- change this for you user ID
        GROUP BY p.provider_entry_type_id, p.provider_entry) y ON y.provider_entry_type_id = x.provider_entry_type_id
                              AND y.max_date = x.created_date
GROUP BY x.provider_entry_type_id
```

Comment: This errors to: Column 'x.created_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You need to wrap it in an aggregate function. In my example, I used Max(x.created_date). Sorry I didn't point that out better.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I know what an aggregate function is but I'm unsure about how to edit the query. Help?

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in my query; I had created_date in the select twice, once in the max function and one without it. I've fixed the query so please copy it and try it again.

Comment: Ok I see the difference, but I still get two results for the provider_entry_type_id  when it equals 132 - I want the *first* one...

Comment: Then provider_entry has to move out of the Group By as well. To get the first one, the function applied should be a MIN. I've fixed the query above.

Comment: this is really close (AND THANK YOU) - question, wouldn't the 'MIN(x.provider_entry)' only give me the MIN entry? I would need whatever provider_entry is associated to provider_entry_id, not min.

Comment: @Macness, you need to add more detail to your question like what you want the query to return and what the table structures are. Otherwise, it's difficult, if not impossible, to provide a query that meets your requirements.